# getting the selected html element offset related to the html source code with js

Tags: javascript

Can I get the offset of a selected html element in the html source code?

for example:

`<html>
      <body>
       <a href="http://google.com">google</a>
      </body>
     <html>`

if the user would select the google text, I would want to get 40 as this is the offset from the start of the source.

I tried with Range object but couldn't find something helpful with this one.

Thanks!

Comment: what do u mean by `in the html source code?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function srcOffset(ele)
{
   alert(document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML.indexOf(ele.id) + ele.id.length + 2);
   return false;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="http://www.google.com/" onclick="return srcOffset(this)" id="myLink">Google</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but what if the element doesn't have id attr?

Comment: Something about the anchor has to be unique, or you'll never be able to tell which link in the source called the JS. You could use the href attribute if you're sure its unique on the page and search for the closing bracket after it. Without uniqueness, you're boned.

Comment: OK I'll try to inject id attr to the anchor node and thus gain uniqueness for the desired element. hope it would do the trick. thanks again.

Comment: `innerHTML` does not necessarily return the same HTML that was returned to the browser, so this is unreliable. Also, all major browsers provide some kind of selection API for getting hold of precisely what content the user has selected, so the uniqueness is a red herring.

Comment: This is not a solution, as in case `ele.id` happens somewhere in document as a part of the text, it won't work. Though, you can walk DOM tree recursively, calculating the length of innerHTML of all the element, which are to the "left" of the one you're searching. If you'd like to do so several times, you'll need to augment DOM nodes with precomputed values to lessen asymptotic complexity from linear to logarithmic.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really do this in a sensible way. The fundamental problem is that there is no way in browsers to get back the original HTML sent by the server; `innerHTML` is often different in some way because it is a representation of the browser's DOM parsed from the original HTML rather than a snippet of the original HTML.

It is possible to retrieve information about the user's selection in all major browsers but this information is expressed in terms of nodes in the browser's DOM rather than as offsets relative to a string containing the original HTML sent by the server.

All that being the case, your best option is retrieving the HTML source again via Ajax and doing complicated HTML parsing to match the browser DOM up with your HTML string, which is non-trivial. It could also be impossible if script running in your page has modified the DOM by the time you get the HTML source back. I would suggest trying to find another way to achieve what you want.

Comment: I found another way to achieve what I want. thank you very much for your reply!

Answer (score -1):

this how you get the offset using jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a").click(function() {
   var offset = $(this).offset();
   alert(offset.left);
      alert(offset.top);
});

});​

<html> <body> 
    <a href="http://google.com" class="first">google</a> 
    <a href="http://abc.com" class="second">abc</a> 
    <a href="http://xyz.com" class="third">xyz</a> 
</body> <html>​

a.first { position:absolute;
    left:20px; top:35px; }
a.second{ position:absolute;
          left:100px; top:35px; }
a.third{ position:absolute;
          left:220px; top:35px; }
```

Demo of this example : http://jsfiddle.net/5YFxH/

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, but this is not what I meant. I know how to positioning an element. but I need its offset in the html code itself. the number of characters from the start of the html source code. sorry if I wasn't clear. any idea for this one?